# Python building a Regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm working with this code and I'm having a hard time finding the correct pattern for this. I can achieve this by altering doing `re.sub` but I want to match without using `re.sub` if possible.

```
var = "77777 11111 12891 22222 i"
```

1. From `var` I want to get only `11111`. Like my code:

   ```
   ppat = re.findall(r'(77777 (?:[\d]{1,6}))', var)
   ```
2. From `var` I want to get the `22222` before the `"i"` like this:

   ```
   opat = re.findall(r'((?:[\d]{1,6}) i)', var)
   ```
3. How do I match these 2 patterns? For example, I'm putting different output to variable which will be matched by the patterns?

a. 1st possible output is:

```
output = "ndescr:  XXXX"
```

b. What pattern should I use to match the `XXXX` and instance that output variable appears like this and I want to get only the **No entries**. What regex pattern should I use?

```
output = "%  No entries found for the selected source(s)"
```

Thanks

Comment: Your use of capturing and non-capturing groups is rather bizarre. You always wrap the whole pattern in an unnecessary capture group for some reason, and you wrap the part you're interested in in a non-capturing group as if that will do something useful.

Comment: Not enough information to derive a practical sample extraction pattern. Based solely on what is written in the original question, you could use `re.findall(r'(0{4,7}|2{4,7}|3{4,7}|4{4,7}|5{4,7}|6{4,7}|7{4,7}|8{4,7}|9{4,7})\s+(\d+)\s+\d+', var)[0][1]`

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. Are you trying to get the second number, of the number  following `77777`? And are you trying to get these both into one variable or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.findall("(?<=77777)\\s+(?:\\d{1,6})",var)
re.findall("(?:\\d{1,6})\\s+(?=i)",aa)
```

you can read python re module for details.
[enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-19)

Comment: you should explain what does the code do, in case someone else stumbles upon this question with a similar problem but not the exact same.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not completely clear what you are trying to match, I am giving it a shot.

If you are just trying to get the second and last element, then this can be done without regular expressions.

```
var = "77777 11111 12891 22222 I"

elements = var.split(" ") # Take the string, and split it into a list on spaces.

first_number = elements[1] # Get the second element ("11111").

second_number = elements[-2] # Get the second element from the end ("22222").
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use regular expressions or are looking for the number after `77777` a regular expression like this would work:

```
import re
var = "77777 11111 12891 22222 I"

# Finds the 5 numbers that follows a "7" repeated 5 times (with a space in between).
first_number = re.search("(?<=7{5}\s)\\d{5}", var).group()

# Find the 5 numbers that precedes an "I" (with a space in between).
second_number = re.search("\\d{5}(?=\sI)", var).group()
```